# Can you change the difficulty mid-game?

Tags: ratchet-deadlocked

There are a couple of skill points throughout the game which are for completing a certain challenge on Exterminator difficulty. From what I've read, you have to beat the game first in order to unlock that difficulty level. I've done so and am now in Challenge Mode. Is there any way to change the difficulty in-game in order to achieve this skill point, or are you required to completely start over and play through the game to those challenges *again*?

Comment: no you can select the difficulty when you load the game from the start screen IIRC

Comment: Sometimes if you die heaps on a particular mission, the game offers to lower the difficulty as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not required to completely start over, you can always change the difficulty of the game when you load your game from the start screen.